# Android Studio - app depends on module's jar

Tags: android, android-studio, shinobi

My app is set up to depend on the module 'shinobicharts-android-library' and everything appears to compile correctly.

The :app itself needs to import classes from a .jar in :shinobicharts-android-library, shouldn't this be accessible if :shinobicharts-android-library is listed as a dependency in :app?

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':shinobicharts-android-library')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is fairly simple.

Yes the jar becomes available to :app, but it must be listed as a dependency in :shinobicharts-android-library

The tutorial I followed gave the incorrect version of the jar.

Note the subtle difference between (shinobicharts-android-library/build.gradle)

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/shinobicharts-android-trial-1.2.0.jar')
    compile files("$buildDir/native-libs/native-libs.jar")
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/shinobicharts-android-trial-1.3.2.jar')
    compile files("$buildDir/native-libs/native-libs.jar")
}
```